# Sending in-app email

Tags: iphone

I need to send an email without exiting the application as the subject and body are already set by the application. I already know how to send an email but I need to exit the application to the email application and click on send to go back to my application. Can't I just send the email without exiting or at least without needing to click on send button, can't there be some sort of a framework that auto-sends the email?

Kind Regards, 
Heba

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code:

(Don't forget to add the messageUI framework to your project!!!)

First import the message framework:

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

then mark your self as a delegate like this

```
@interface MYViewController () <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

then to pull up the composer:

```
- (IBAction)supportPressed:(id)sender
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *composeViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [composeViewController setMailComposeDelegate:self];
        [composeViewController setToRecipients:@[@"example@email.com"]];
        [composeViewController setSubject:@"example subject"];
        [self presentViewController:composeViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

Then to handle the delegate callback and dismiss the composer:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    //Add an alert in case of failure
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use MFMailComposeViewController to send in-app email. You can use this code inside one of your view controllers (for example, in response to a button press). Note that you will need to add the MessageUI framework to your app.

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

The code to present the mail view controller:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[mail setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email@example.com"]];
[mail setSubject:@"Set The Subject Here"];    

[self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];
```

See the documentation for how to implement the mailComposeDelegate - you can use this to dismiss the modal view controller when the email is sent or the user has canceled the task.

Answer (score 0):

Look for [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) . Also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182058/not-receiving-attachments-sent-from-mfmailcomposer) post

Answer (score 0):

To send email within the app you can use the `MFMailComposeViewController` class.

Like this:

```
if( [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] ) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [mailViewController setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"mail@address.com"]];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
    [mailViewController release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this short code if you are not able to hard code: < a href="mailto:example@example.com" >Send Mail< /a >